# How to use another variable in Ansible variable?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

How to make the echo statement here correct？When I use Ansible `debug` module is able to correctly get the value, but not in the shell module.

```
cat /data/info.txt
a:8080,b:8081,c:8082
```

```
cat /data/num
0
```

```
 - hosts: dev
   remote_user: root
   gather_facts: false
   tasks:
     - name: get dir path and port info
       shell: cat /data/info.txt
       register: info

     - name: get the last num
       shell: cat /data/num
       register: num

     - name: test
       shell: echo {{ info.stdout.split(',')[{{ num.stdout }}].split(':')[0] }} >>/tmp/test.txt
```

Comment: sorry,I have read the document, but I still did not solve this problem, you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open a Jinja2 expression with `{{`, you should use bare variables until it is terminated with `}}`. Quoting the [FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names):

> Another rule is ‘moustaches don’t stack’. We often see this:
>
> ```
> {{ somevar_{{other_var}} }}
> ```
>
> The above DOES NOT WORK

---

What you might be looking for (because you still didn't include your expected result) is:

```
shell: echo {{ info.stdout.split(',')[ num.stdout|int ].split(':')[0] }} >>/tmp/test.txt
```

On top of not stacking the moustaches, you need to pay attention to types and cast the second value (retrieved from `/data/num`) to integer.

Comment: The most important thing is to convert the standard output to int.